windowSoftInputMode adjustResize doesn't work in target sdk 35
When I increased the target SDK of the app from 34 to 35, the windowSoftInputMode in adjustResize mode no longer worked. I have tested everything and found that it is only related to the target SDK. For example, I tested it on different devices with different versions of Android and it didn't work, I tested it in several activities with different layouts, I tested it in different windowSoftInputMode modes, I also tested fitsSystemWindows. It didn't work in any case and I'm pretty sure it's related to target SDK 35. But after hours of trying I didn't find any solution for it.
The problem is this: I have an activity with the value android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in the manifest, which in target SDK 35, when the keyboard is opened, the layout is not placed on top of the keyboard and the keyboard covers the screens, but in target SDK 34 and below, this problem does not exist.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".view.RegisterNameActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_6"
        android:tint="?colorOnSurface"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back_24" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/iran_sans_demi_bold"
        android:text="@string/your_name"
        android:textColor="?colorOnSurface"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_26"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/description"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_32"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_4"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_32"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_8"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_8"
        android:text="@string/your_name_and_bio_description"
        android:textColor="?colorOnSurfaceVariant"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_14"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_32"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_32"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_32"
        android:backgroundTint="?colorOnSurface"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/name_required"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_8"
        android:paddingEnd="36dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bio"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/nameLength"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_4"
        android:textColor="?colorOnSurfaceVariant"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_10"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
        tools:text="0/25" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/nameError"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_8"
        android:textColor="?colorError"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_10"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/nameLength"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
        tools:text="Please enter your name"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/clearName"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-3dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:tint="?colorOnSurfaceVariant"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/name"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_16"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/bio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
        android:backgroundTint="?colorOnSurface"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/biography_optional"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_8"
        android:paddingEnd="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/termsAndConditions"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/clearBio"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-3dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:tint="?colorOnSurfaceVariant"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bio"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bio"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bio"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_16"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/bioLength"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_4"
        android:textColor="?colorOnSurfaceVariant"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_10"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bio"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bio"
        tools:text="0/256" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/termsAndConditions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_32"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_32"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:textColor="?colorOnSurfaceVariant"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_12"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/submitFab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/submitFab"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/submitFab"
        tools:text="By registering, you agree to the terms and conditions of using the App." />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/submitFab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_24"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:rippleColor="?colorOnPrimaryContainer"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_done_24"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,NotSibling" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

